# Below is a diagram of the dotted cube with edges of length 4

Tags: vectors

Below is a diagram of the dotted cube with edges of length 4

[image]

**my attempt:** 
t=-u+v=(-4,4,0)

t-2r=(-4,4,0)-2(-4,4,4)=(4,-4,-8)

u+v+w+r+s+t=(4,0,0)+(0,4,0)+(0,0,4)+(-4,4,4)+(4,-4,4)+(-4,4,4)=(0,8,16)

is  i am right can any one give me right direction

Comment: Your answer for part 2 is wrong because it doesn't match your work, which is correct

Comment: @Triatticus..why can you explain me

Comment: Your work indicates $(-4,4,0)$ yet you put in the vector $(-4,-4,0)$ as your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$t-2r=(-4,4,0)-2(4,4,4)=(-12,-4,-8)$$

$$u+v+w+r+s+t=u+v+w+u+v+w+u+w+v-u=$$
$$=2u+3v+3w=(8,12,12)$$

Comment: how  you got t =(-4,4,4)

Comment: i don 't understand how  you got t coz t is in the direction u and v only

Comment: again i have question when you calculated r , u is the opposite direction of r is we choose -u

Comment: @P suresh It was, typo. $r=u+v+w$ by the sum definition of vectors.